# why is there a (-11-System Error) whenever i run sudo apt-get update?

Tags: apt, update-manager, system

why is there a (-11-System Error) whenever i run sudo apt-get update?

Something wicked happened resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-11 - System error)

Comment: The root issue is DNS. Check for useful response (or error codes) when you run: **`dig archive.ubuntu.com`**

Answer (score 0):

Close all programs/windows which have to do with installing software e.g. Synaptic, software-centre and terminals.

Now you should delete the locked files:

> You can delete the lock file with
>
> ```
> sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
> ```
>
> you may also need to delete the lock file in the cache directory
>
> ```
> sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
> ```

and now you should open a terminal and run:

```
 sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

Comment: How does this deal with the failure to resolve the hostname?